# Excel create date stamp when an cell is updated

Tags: excel

I have this excel sheet that has a 'last updated' field in column N. I need to make this an automatic update to todays date, whenever the status in column H is changed for that row.

Can anyone help on a simple solution?

Thank you in advance!
Kriss

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the following *event Macro* in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim rng As Range, r As Range, H As Range
  Set H = Range("H:H")
  Set rng = Intersect(H, Target)
  If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

  Application.EnableEvents = False
  For Each r In rng
    Cells(r.Row, "N").Value = Date
  Next r
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you very much for a very quick and easy solution!